# Ios Swift Sharing on WhatsApp and FB

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, share, whatsapp

I am experiencing a few issue with the Share option in iOS8.

With the below code I am able to correctly share by Email and Text(SMS) including my text strings and my image.
But when I try to share to Facebook, the generated post only includes my image (skipping the text strings) while if I try to share on WhatsApp, the image is skipped and only the text strings are passed.

Does anybody have any suggestion?

My code:

```
@IBAction func shareButtonClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    var kidToShare1 : String? = noKids


    if selectedKid == nil {
        kidToShare1 = noKids
        println("kid is nil")
    } else {
        kidToShare1 = selectedKid!.kidName
    }
    let kidToShare = NSLocalizedString("Kid: ", comment:"Kid to share") + kidToShare1!
    let imageToShare = photo! ?? noPhoto!
    let textToShare = NSLocalizedString("Event Description: ", comment:"Text to share") + descriptionText as NSString
    let dateToShare = NSLocalizedString("Event Date: ", comment: "Date to share") + formatDate(date) as NSString
    let message = NSLocalizedString("My App", comment: "Main sharing message")
    let objectsToShare = [message, dateToShare, kidToShare, textToShare, imageToShare]

    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)      

    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,UIActivityTypePrint]

    self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about sharing with WhatsApp, but for Facebook, [this bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/962985360399542/) could be relevant to you. In short, pre-filling the share sheet is not allowed according Facebook Platform Policy.

Comment: Thank you for the link! Still looking for some info for whatsapp but seems impossible to find ...